# PHP How to split multi dimensional array into single array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Simple code that i use to get array results:

```
require_once 'connect_to_mysql.php';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM protect";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$db_array = array();
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $db_array[] = $row;
        }
    }
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($db_array);
    echo '</pre>';
```

I get the following array from database:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [words] => cat
            [keyword] => nice cat
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [words] => good dog
            [keyword] => dog training
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [words] => love birds
            [keyword] => birds
        )

)
```

i wish to get this all data in a single array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => cat
    [1] => good dog
    [2] => love birds
)
```

Could you please tell how i can do so?
Thank you.

Comment: Why not just only add the row `words` to your array here: `$db_array[] = $row;`?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your `while()` loop in the following way,

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $db_array[] = $row['words'];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just change your query,no need to get data you don`t use

```
$sql = "SELECT words FROM protect";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the function [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php):

```
$smaller = array_column($db_array, 'words')
```